# (C) Scanf - input gets 0 every time

Tags: c, input, char, output, scanf

Each time i set a value in **b** after **a**, the value is reset to **0** in **a**.
In other words, as the code goes, no matter what i input in **a** it will be always **0** after the second scanf function.

EDIT: I need to use b as char type for the essay, for memory efficiency, so i can't set b to int, but i need to input integer in there.

EDIT2: I need to input an integer in b, example for an input:

1

2

from that point if i

> printf("%d",a);

i get 0.

```
unsigned short a;
char b;
scanf("%hu",&a);
scanf("%d",&b);
```

Comment: `"%d"` in `scanf()` expects a pointer to `int`. You are passing a pointer to `char` and invoking **Undefined Behaviour**. Try `int b;`.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the integer value is between `CHAR_MIN` (-127) and `CHAR_MAX` (127)? Or, to pose a general question: What is the range of the second value you're reading?

Comment: The question edit says you want to input an integer value in `b`. This can only be a **single digit** in the range 0..9 which then needs an adjustment from its character value (usually ASCII), such as with `scanf(" %c", &b); b -= '0';`.

Comment: @meaning-matters Yes it's guaranteed.

Comment: @xing perfect! can you add this comment as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `char b;` and `scanf("%d",&b);`, scanf will write `sizeof (int)` bytes to b.
This will corrupt other memory.
`scanf("%hhd",&b);` will only write one byte to b.

Answer (score 1):

`%d` requires an `int`:

```
int b;
```

Then, you should check the return value of your `scanf()` calls. Do both calls return `1`?

(`scanf()` returns the number of input items assigned. Because both your calls have one `%...`, you must return `1` in both cases.)

Comment: I need to use b as char type for the essay, for memory efficiency.

Comment: In that case [Weather Vane's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54967144/1971013) is what you need. In any case, do check if the return value of `scanf()` is `1`.

Comment: @artmo-CSstudent there isn't enough information in the question. Please show an example input.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong format specifier with

```
scanf("%d", &b);
```

It should be

```
scanf("%c", &b);
```

However since there is a previous `scanf` statement there is a newline still in the buffer, and to filter that out you can use

```
scanf(" %c", &b);
```

Most format specifiers automatically filter out leading whitespace but `%c` and `%[]` and `%n` do not.

It is unclear from the mistake whether the format specifier is at fault, or the variable type.